# progmem data array optimized out

Tags: attiny, avr-gcc

I try to use a ATTiny10 to drive some APA102 LEDs.
The LEDs are arranged in a 5x5 array. To draw something I stored some 'images' in PROGMEM. Program looks like this:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <stdint.h>

unsigned char brightness = 12;

const unsigned char i[]  PROGMEM = {
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
};

const unsigned char o[]  PROGMEM = {
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00
};
*/
const unsigned char u[]  PROGMEM = {
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
};

void delay (int millis) {
  for (volatile unsigned int i = 34*millis; i>0; i--);
}

// send clock on PB0 and data on PB1
void sendByte(const unsigned char byte){
   //bit banging stuff here
}

void show(const unsigned char *data){
  // send header
  sendByte(0x00);
  sendByte(0x00);
  sendByte(0x00);
  sendByte(0x00);

  // send data
  for (unsigned char led = 0; led < 25; led = ++led){
    sendByte(0xE0 + brightness);            // brightness
    sendByte(pgm_read_byte(data[led]));     // blue   
    sendByte(pgm_read_byte(data[led+1]));   // green
    sendByte(pgm_read_byte(data[led+2]));   // red
  }

  // send foooter
  sendByte(0xFF);
  sendByte(0xFF);
  sendByte(0xFF);
  sendByte(0xFF);
}

void setup(){
  DDRB = 3;                       // PB0 and PB1 as an output
}


int main (void) {
  setup();

  while (1){
    show(i);
    delay(100);
    show(o);
    delay(100);
    show(u);
    delay(100);
  }
}
```

What confuses me is the output of the compiler.
No matter how many character arrays I add always get the result 186 bytes used.

```
DATA:    [          ]   0.0% (used 0 bytes from 32 bytes)
PROGRAM: [==        ]  18.2% (used 186 bytes from 1024 bytes)
```

What I would expect is something > 225 byte (3 characters * 3 byte per color * 25 LEDS)

As it seems the the PROGMEM arrays are optimized out by the compiler.

when I change the main to following (ignore the nonsense of the operation):

```
int main (void) {
  setup();

  char d = pgm_read_byte(i);
  char e = pgm_read_byte(o);
  char f = pgm_read_byte(u);

  while (d>e && e < f){
    show(i);
    delay(100);
    show(o);
    delay(100);
    show(u);
    delay(100);
 }
}
```

this results in the expected size:

```
DATA:    [          ]   0.0% (used 0 bytes from 32 bytes)
PROGRAM: [====      ]  44.9% (used 460 bytes from 1024 bytes)
```

This means compiler looses track of the usage of i,o and u by passing them as pointer to show? Have I missed something by passing the data arrays?

I use VS Code + PlatformIO with latest AVR environment (avr-g++ 5.4.0)

**UPDATE**:

I don't know why this made the difference but when passing it as PGM_VOID_P aka const void* and casting it inside the function it works!

```c
void show(PGM_VOID_P data_p){
  const uint8_t* data = (const uint8_t*)data_p;
```

Comment: Does the code work? What does the assembly code look like? It may be that some of your constants are optimized away.

Comment: No it does not work otherwise I wouldn't ask ;) I had a look at both hex outputs and in the short one the arrays are missing

Comment: How does it not work? What result did you expect and what actually happened when you ran the code?

Comment: Also, where is `pgm_read_byte` defined?

Comment: It does not output anything on the GPIOs. I can't debug the attiny10. 
pgm_read_byte is included from avr/pgmspace.h

Comment: One thing, your indexing in `show` is off. You should either allow the for loop to get up to `led < 75`, or you should be referencing `data[3*led+...]` and incrementing `led` by 1. Otherwise you're only ever looking at every third line of the data in your character arrays. I'd be very surprised if your compiler is able to figure this out and optimize away 2/3 of the arrays though.

Comment: Your function declaration `void show(const unsigned char *data)` strips the `PROGMEM` attribute from the parameter, so inside `show` you're accessing some other memory location. It should probably be something like `void show(const unsigned char * PROGMEM data)`.

Comment: @brhans I edited show function as suggested but nothing changed

Comment: I see the variable i is used both as global PROGMEM array and in delay; it should not matter, but you could try using different variable names; also maybe change i, o and u into longer names to prevent being used/interfered with other files.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the AVR compiler's syntax, so you might need to put the `PROGMEM` keyword somewhere else in the `show` declaration. If you enable all of your compiler's warning options you'll probably see it warn you on the lines you call `show` that you're losing some attribute of your pointer.

Comment: You need to look at the disassembled **code**, not at the hex listings. And if you don't tell us what your program actually does or does not do then we can not help you.

Answer (score 2):

I tried compiling your code with avr-gcc 4.9.2 and 5.4.0, and in both cases the array data was put into flash program memory. However the function `sendByte` does nothing, so *reading* the data was optimized out.

So I added some minimal code to 'send' the data, and the compiler generated this:-

```
000000ac <i>:
 ac:    00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00     ................
 bc:    00 00 00 00 00 ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     ................
 cc:    00 00 00 00 ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00     ................
 dc:    00 00 00 ff ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ff     ................
 ec:    ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 00 00 00                 ............
...
    show(i);
174:    8c ea           ldi r24, 0xAC       
176:    90 e4           ldi r25, 0x40       
...
    sendByte(pgm_read_byte(data[led]));     // blue
12c:    a8 2f           mov     r26, r24
12e:    b9 2f           mov     r27, r25
130:    ec 91           ld      r30, X
132:    f0 e0           ldi     r31, 0x00   
134:    f0 5c           subi    r31, 0xC0   
136:    e0 81           ld      r30, Z

    void sendByte(const unsigned char byte){
      PORTB = byte;
138:    e2 b9           out     0x02, r30
```

We see that registers r24 and r25 are loaded with the address `0x40AC`, which is the data memory address corresponding to flash program memory address `0x00AC` (our array data). Further down we see r24/r25 copied into r26/r27 (the 'X' address pointer) and r30 loaded from that memory location (your LED data byte). However that value is then used as the low byte of *another* address, loading r30 *again* via r30/r31 (the Z address pointer)!

This is wrong. Why?

`pgm_read_byte()` takes as its argument a program memory **address**, so you must  give it the **address** of your array element (not its value) using the '&' operator; ie.

```
sendByte(pgm_read_byte(&data[led]));
```

With this change the generated code becomes:-

```
    sendByte(pgm_read_byte(&data[led]));     // blue   
 12e:   e8 2f           mov r30, r24
 130:   f9 2f           mov r31, r25
 132:   60 81           ld  r22, Z

void sendByte(const unsigned char byte){
   PORTB = byte;
 134:   62 b9           out 0x02, r22
```

Now the LED data byte is simply read from the array into r22, then output via `sendByte()`.

Hopefully this will work for you (I don't have an ATTiny10 or a simulator for it, so I can't verify that the compiler is generating the correct code). Later versions of gcc can use the attribute `__flash` instead of `PROGMEM`, which may be easier to work with.

Comment: I change the call to an address as sugested but did not change the result :( Which options / flags did you use?

Comment: Compiler flags:- "-Wall -gdwarf-2 -std=gnu99 -Os -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums". Are your arrays still being optimized out?

Comment: It's still optimized out. Even with your flags :( also tried __flash but nothing changed

Comment: I compiled the exact same code as you posted here (except for replacing `//bit banging stuff here` with `PORTB = byte;`) using the same compiler (avr_gcc v5.4.0) and - as expected - it did not optimize out the arrays. The usual reason for code being optimized out is that it has no effect on the final output, so make sure your  `sendByte()` function is actually using the array data! `__flash` eliminates the need for  `pgm_read_byte()` when referencing data in ROM (read compiler documentation on how to use it).

Comment: I also tested the sendByte  with `sendByte(pgm_read_byte(&i[0]);` in main which prevented i to be optimized out